# custom controller with extension

Tags: controller, controller-extension, custom, custom-controller

What are some use cases in having a **custom controller** with extensions?
Does it make sense to have something like this?

EDIT2
Edited out the error I was receiving - apparently in my extension I was asking for a standardController in my constructor argument when in fact I was using a customController. I just used the class as the parameter instead

Comment: You might use an extension if you want the functionality to be reusable across different pages. One example I have used is a page count.

Comment: @Girbot You should write this up as an answer...

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to have an extension for a custom controller.

Let's say my custom controller is this:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
...
}
```

My extension could then have a contructor that is called when this class is the controller for a page:

```
public with sharing class MyExtension {
...
  public MyExtension(MyController ctrlParam) {

  }
}
```

You could have the same extension work for both ApexPage.StandardController and some custom controller, but you'd need to overload the constructor:

```
public with sharing class MyExtension {
...
  public MyExtension(MyController ctrlParam) {

  }

  public MyExtension(StandardController ctrlParam) {

  }
}
```

If you want your extension to be reused for a lot of controllers, you might need to plan ahead and use inheritance either from a superclass or an interface so that you don't end up with too many constructors.

I suspect that most customer implementations do not get to this degree of sophistication. Where I would expect this model to crop up more often is in AppExchange app architecture.

Comment: Thank you! but I just found out what was wrong with it myself and you were spot on. As for your answer to my original question: Thank you for your response and input.